# Execute python script at launch time on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am trying to execute a python script on an Amazon Linux 2 instance. In my `user-data` section I have a script which copies the python script from an S3 bucket to the instance and executes it like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

# e - stops the script if there is an error
# x - output every command in /var/log/syslog
set -e -x

# set AWS region
echo "export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1" >> /etc/profile
source /etc/profile
# copy python script from the s3 bucket
aws s3 cp s3://${bucket_name}/ /home/ec2-user --recursive

sudo python3 my_python_script.py
```

The problem is that the python script doesn't seem to be getting executed at all.

**Note**: the python script gets copied fine from the bucket

What I am missing here?

**UPDATE**:
after checking `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` it looks like the problem is in the python script, it cannot find the `boto3` module:

```
+ python3 /home/ec2-user/my_python_script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/my_python_script.py", line 1, in <module>
    import boto3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'
Dec 10 15:52:25 cloud-init[3697]: util.py[WARNING]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001 [1]
Dec 10 15:52:25 cloud-init[3697]: cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
Dec 10 15:52:25 cloud-init[3697]: util.py[WARNING]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.pyc'>) failed
```

The problem is that I do have `boto3` module installed. I created a custom AMI image that does have all of the modules installed (I used `pip3` to install them) before creating the custom AMI image

**UPDATE2**

I verified that the image does have `boto3` package installed in the `python3` library:

```
[ec2-user@ip-ip ~]$ python3
Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 27 2020, 21:59:41)
[GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-9)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
>>>
```

**UPDATE3**

The cause of the problem was that I installed the `boto3` package for my `user` only (i.e. `pip3 install boto3 --user`) and then I created the AMI image. So after adding the bellow line to my `user-data` script it worked fine

```
#!/bin/bash

...
sudo pip3 install boto3
sudo python3 my_python_script.py
```

Comment: Maybe log the output and stderr of that command to a file somewhere? What user is the userdata executing as, isn't it run as root already?

Comment: I am pretty sure that when the instance launches it executes the user-data as root

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html "Scripts entered as user data are run as the root user, so do not use the sudo command in the script."

Comment: Thanks, I will remove the `sudo` command. Howver, I did try without `sudo` before and the python script was still not getting executed :/

Comment: Can you log the stdout and stderr output of the python3 invocation?

Comment: Hmm. you're copying the bucket content to `/home/ec2-user` but I'm not sure if the userdata executes from that directory - so `python3 my_python_script.py` maybe just can't find `my_python_script.py` in the working directory?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I can try to see if I will be able to capture strerr from user-data (never done it before). As for, the script location, that's a good point. It may not be able to find it

Comment: try `python3 /home/ec2-user/my_python_script.py`

Comment: @Asdfg thank you. I tried that but unfortunately, it is still not being called (I am using `htop` to verify if it runs as it should spike the memory usage quite a bit). I am looking at ways to capture any errors from `user-data`

Comment: check `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` to see whats going on. Also try executing the script manually from `/var/lib/cloud/instances/<<instance-id>>`

Comment: Thanks! I checked that file just now and it looks like the problem is in the python script itself :/ I will update the question

Comment: just do `pip install boto3` before you execute the python script.

Comment: Thanks @Asdfg but that image do have that library installed. I did noticed that the `cloud-init` seems to be using `Python2.7` (I added more lines to the error output in my question). Do you know how I might force the user data to be using the already installed `Python3.8`?

Comment: ‘python3’ uses Python 3.x version. You probably installed ’boto3’ with python2.7 when you created the image.

Comment: I did verify that the image does have the `boto3` package installed already. I updated my question

Comment: I updated my question with the root cause of my issue. It was because I installed `boto3` package just for the `ec2-user` user and when the user-data script was getting executed, it was as `root` and it was not finding the `boto3` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect output to a file and read it to see the error: did you have python3, did your instance have credentianl/role to access this bucket, did you script requires any third party, can you try to run the script above as `root` in local first, the run command should be `python3 /home/ec2-user/my_python_script.py`?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I don't think that is the reason why my script is not getting executed. I have checked the `/etc/profile` file contents after the instance launches and it does contain my exported environment variable

Comment: The instance does have credentials to copy the file from the bucket. I verified that after I sshed to the instance I saw the file in `home/ec2-user`

Comment: Can you please send me the output of `cd ~ && ls` and `python3 /home/ec2-user/my_python_script.py`

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with the relevant data. It looks like my problem comes from my python script. It cannot find `boto3` (i.e. a library that my script relies on)

Comment: you should install it first  @GeorgiKoemdzhiev, I am not familiar with python maybe `pip install boto3` or `pip3 install boto3` before `sudo python3 /home/ec2-user/my_python_script.py` should help

Comment: Thank you. I added a few more lines in my question and it looks like at boot time the version of python is `2.7` instead of the already installed `Python3.8`

Comment: I think you can specific path to python3, for example `/usr/bin/python3 path/to/your/script` (I got this when use `which python3`)

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and it did show that `python3` is located in a different place - `/usr/bin/python3`. I did try running that but it is still using `python2.7`. I checked `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`, does that mean that I will just have to install `python3` as `root`?

Comment: I updated my question with the root cause of my issue. It was because I installed `boto3` package just for the `ec2-user` user and when the user-data script was getting executed, it was as `root` and it was not finding the `boto3` package

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev, it is my expected, I think you can add python3 to your PATH (when you build your image) in `~/.profile`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14638025/10671200

Comment: Or you can use absolute path for python3

Comment: Thank you! Will try that :)

Comment: You can try to add python3 to your PATH in /etc/environment also or use absolute python3 path instead of just python3 your/path/to/yourscript, just like other answer in the link above

Comment: I will build a new image following your advice and see what happens :) Ideally, all of the packages should be available when I launch the server (i.e. I don't have to install them at boot time)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is using cloudinit and terraform, this is how I managed it to work (one part of multipart cloudinit user data)-

```
part {
    content_type      = "text/x-shellscript"
    filename          = "run_src.sh"
    content           = <<-EOF
      #!/bin/bash
      cd /root
      mkdir tmp
      mkdir tmp/origin
      mkdir tmp/converted
      mkdir tmp/packaged
      
      pip3 install boto3
      cd src

      python3 main.py

    EOF
  }
```

And it works like charm.