# qmake installed but not found

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I installed **qt5** in my computer as shown below:

```
ed@Mars:/usr/lib/qt5/bin$ ls -la total 7956 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 may 30 20:42 . drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 abr  8 10:26 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    6340 abr  9  2020 fixqt4headers.pl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  907576 abr  9  2020 moc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  301360 abr  9  2020 qdbuscpp2xml
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   88288 abr  9  2020 qdbusxml2cpp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1762296 abr 10  2020 qdoc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  211248 abr 10  2020 qhelpgenerator
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  227632 abr  9  2020 qlalr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2972304 abr  9  2020 qmake
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   71904 abr 10  2020 qtattributionsscanner
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   43232 abr  9  2020 qvkgen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  846136 abr  9  2020 rcc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   48144 abr  9  2020 syncqt.pl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  629040 abr  9  2020 uic
```

however, when I check my **qmake** version **Ubuntu 20.04** displays:

```
ed@Mars:/usr/lib/qt5/bin$ qmake --version

Command 'qmake' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install qtchooser
```

Any hint on how to make **qmake** visible and executable,

Comment: Type `./qmake --version` from that folder. Related: [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-dot-slash-to-execute-a-file-in-linux-unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-dot-slash-to-execute-a-file-in-linux-unix)

Comment: is it possible you installed qt5 in a different way? pretty sure your error can (among many other solutions) fixed by running `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/qt5/bin"`

Comment: @kritzikratzi right, problem solved ! The Qt installation was fine. The problem was that I have not included it in the environment variable $PATH. For those interested, that's in the .profile file in Ubuntu.

Comment: great! i'm gonna vote to close, because it's really a bash/ubuntu error in your specific setup and don't think it's gonna be helpful much for other people in the future

Comment: well, i messed up and now i can't close it anymore. anyways, i think this can be considered a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14637979/347508