# Why webdiff didn't show?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git

I try to install `webdiff` and use it. Install command:

```
❯ pip install webdiff
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: webdiff in /home/song/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyGithub==1.25.2 in /home/song/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from webdiff) (1.25.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from webdiff) (2.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from webdiff) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: flask in /home/song/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from webdiff) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: binaryornot in /home/song/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from webdiff) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet>=3.0.2 in /home/song/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from binaryornot->webdiff) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=2.0 in /home/song/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask->webdiff) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.0 in /home/song/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask->webdiff) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.0 in /home/song/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask->webdiff) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=7.1.2 in /home/song/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask->webdiff) (8.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /home/song/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Jinja2>=3.0->flask->webdiff) (2.0.1)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.2; however, version 21.1.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

However when I run `git webdiff`, the output is:

```
❯ git webdiff
git: 'webdiff' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip show --files webdiff
```

See in what directory `pip` has installed the script `git-webdiff`. In your case I think the directory is `/home/song/.local/bin/`. [Add the directory to the `$PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962251/7976758).

Comment: And after adding the path, here is another error: 
```
╰─ git webdiff                                                                                                                                                                                              ─╯
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 68, in <module>
    from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
warning: failed: 1
```

Comment: That's a different question and should be asked separately with a full text of the traceback. `_imaging` is a shared library; try to reinstall PIL: `pip install --force-reinstall pillow`