# How to open Visual Studio Code from the command line on RHEL?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rhel

I would like to open VSCode from my RHEL terminal using the `code` command but when I try to type `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH` directly in VSCode Command Palette, it indicates that `No matching command is found`. Is there a way to configure `$PATH` directly via the command line to make `code` work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to permanently set $PATH on Linux/Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix)

Comment: Try `/usr/local/bin/code`. if it working, set PATH: `PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"`. To make it permanently, write is to your `.bash_profile`

Comment: @ExDoors I tried to see ```/usr/local/bin/code``` and its does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally what worked for me was to run the following commands :

```
sudo rpm --import https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
```

```
dnf check-update
```

```
sudo dnf install code
```