# Setting up Python (via Homebrew) on M1 Mac #pip #pipenv

Tags: python, pip, path, homebrew, pipenv

I just tried to setup python by myself on my new M1 Mac. Last time I did it with anaconda but now I wanted to try it the manual way.

So I installed Homebrew and installed Python3 via Homebrew (that comes with pip3).
The last thing I wanted to do is installing pipenv and now I need some advice:

```
Installing collected packages: certifi, virtualenv-clone, platformdirs, backports.entry-points-selectable, distlib, filelock, virtualenv, pipenv
  WARNING: The script virtualenv-clone is installed in '/Users/lukas/Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script virtualenv is installed in '/Users/lukas/Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts pipenv and pipenv-resolver are installed in '/Users/lukas/Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed backports.entry-points-selectable-1.1.1 certifi-2021.10.8 distlib-0.3.3 filelock-3.4.0 pipenv-2021.11.23 platformdirs-2.4.0 virtualenv-20.10.0 virtualenv-clone-0.5.7
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
lukas@Lukas-MBP ~ % which pipenv
pipenv not found
```

I think pipenv is not found because it is not in my PATH. Now I checked out some online videos about adding directories to my PATH but did not find a solution explainable for me.

Maybe someone can help me out. Did I install pipenv the right way and how do I get the directory linked to my PATH.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962251/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bshell%5D+Add+to+PATH