# running a java program under a specific version of java

Tags: java, linux, bash

java versions installed on my linux machine

sudo update-alternatives --config java

/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle/bin/java

/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle/bin/java

/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

how do i make a file .sh, which runs my program under java version 1.8 without changing the standard version of java

My script does not work

/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/ --exec java /home/alex/xmind/XMind_amd64/XMind

Thanks

Comment: What's the command to run it without specifying a version?

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you need to understand how a program is called from the shell.

If your technology is called acme, located **/usr/foo/acme-app/bin/acme**, you should add it to the special variable environment called **PATH**

```
export ACME_HOME=/usr/foo/acme-app/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ACME_HOME/bin
```

Just after that, acme could be used in the shell

```
acme --help
```

Some installers do it at installation step but in some cases you need to do it manually.

In your case to have a specific version

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

or

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

After that you could confirm the version with

```
java -version
```

Sometimes the PATH is dirty with due to your previous installations. I mean in the PATH there are several java versions. You could check with

```
echo $PATH
```

If there are several java versions in the path, you just need to erase them and export a new PATH. Here an example of clean and minimal PATH:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

And other no so clean

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java5
```

In that case, you just need to fix the PATH and add only one java version

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

> Note: This works while the shell is open. If it is closed or in another shell, PATH is restored. Toset this permanently, check this: [How to permanently set $PATH on Linux/Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix)

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way.
Declare JAVA_HOME
Call java from JAVA_HOME

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin/java /path/to/your/program
```

Comment: This is bad advice.  Though this kind of works, most Java tools that use `JAVA_HOME` would expect it to point to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/", not "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin".

Comment: @StephenC: changed

Comment: Still not right

Comment: For example, later Java versions don't have a jre directory ... in the OpenJDK packaging for Ubuntu for example.

Comment: @StephenC .. I see.. Thx