# Cannot use pintos by ssh

Tags: ssh, operating-system, pintos

I use a docker container to try pintos on my mac(M1). Everything behaves well when I start the container by `docker start -i pintos`.

However, when I use ssh to connect my docker container(i.e., `ssh -p xxxx root@local`), error message `-bash: pintos: command not found` occurs if I try `pintos --` in directory `/pintos/src/threads/build`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the pintos executable is in your $PATH. Type

```
$ echo $PATH
```

and make sure the pintos binary is located in one of the folders listed. If not add the executable to your PATH (as described here: [How to permanently set $PATH on Linux/Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix)) or write the full path to it.