# macOS "PATH" Is not getting updated at all after several tries

Tags: macos, terminal, environment-variables, zsh, bin

At my new Organization,

I have a new MacBook Pro. (Ventura 13.x.x)
when I try to set the path using PATH command

in Zshell

Commands I ran

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/xxx/xxx/Drivers/apache-maven-3.9.3/bin

source ~/ .zshrc

export -f

echo $PATH
```

**Now I can see path got updated after above.**

Later When I close the terminal and relaunch it **PATH is not updated with the change I made**

I tried Restarting my Mac couple of times, did the same work too many times.

I do have permissions on my Mac

> -rw-r--r--  1 xxxx  staff  349 Jun 29 17:35 .zshrc

I am not sure When I open my paths file, maven is pointed there,

But still no luck.
***Please help me out with your tips and tricks.***

Comment: What changes you made and to what file?

Comment: I have made the changes to PATHS file in /etc/paths

Comment: How you updated it? Maybe you made a typo? You do not give enough details.

Comment: I have downloaded the maven zip and unzipped it 

Then I copied the bin path

Then I opened the terminal ran the above commands in the sequence I specified,
When I run echo $path command I can see the path got appended.
Tested mvn from the same terminal.
Later I closed again I launched the terminal but now terminal says

Command not found: "zsh: command not found: mvn"

to make sure I have opened the PATHS file in text editor, I can see it got appended.
but still when I run echo $PATH in new terminal, it does not show the maven path in terminal.

Please lMK if you need more info

Comment: When you say "PATHS file", do you mean the actual `/etc/paths` file? Did you remember to save it after editing?

Comment: Environment variables are passed from parent to child process only. Not to parents or siblings. The behaviour is expected.

Comment: @svlasov

Yes I did save it back.

Comment: @ulrich-eckhardt
How do I resolve this now, also can you be little more detailed if possible?

Comment: @Maheshkumar I think you're very confused about what things control what when it comes to your `PATH`. Running `source ~/.zshrc` doesn't save changes in your current shell into the permanent ~/.zshrc file, it does pretty much the reverse: it applies the settings in ~/.zshrc to your current shell. If you want to make a change that'll affect future shells, you need to edit ~/.zshrc *and then use `source ~/.zshrc` to apply that change to the current shell*.

Comment: @gordon-davisson

Thanks this has worked.
Really great help.  
I will make this as an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to permanently set $PATH on Linux/Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix)

Comment: I recommend against manually changing /etc/paths. In particular don't put directories below `/Users` there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're very confused about what things control what when it comes to your PATH. Running source ~/.zshrc doesn't save changes in your current shell into the permanent ~/.zshrc file, it does pretty much the reverse: it applies the settings in ~/.zshrc to your current shell. If you want to make a change that'll affect future shells, you need to edit ~/.zshrc and then use source ~/.zshrc to apply that change to the current shell. –

#Gordon Davisson Thanks for your answer.