# Unable to Install Heroku toolbelt on Samsung ARM Chromebook?

Tags: heroku, apt-get

I have a Samsung Series 3 Chromebook with the ARM processor.  I made a Crouton `chroot` and installed Ubuntu cli.  I have Node.js 0.10.15 installed and running.  I tried to install the `heroku-toolbelt` and it won't run.  Below is the command:

`(precise)root@localhost:/# wget --no-check-certificate -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh`

I used `--no-check-certificate` because when I took quiet mode off I learned that was causing the install to punt.  After it told me a few times it could not verify certificates, it did said:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
Get:1 http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release.gpg [490 B]
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg           
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise Release
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release
Get:2 http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release [1,673 B]                 
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release                             
and a whole lot more Hit http://......
```

After which it said:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates foreman git git-core git-man heroku libasn1-8-heimdal libcurl3-gnutls liberror-perl libgcrypt11 libgnutls26 libgpg-error0
  libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libkrb5-26-heimdal libldap-2.4-2 libp11-kit0
  libroken18-heimdal librtmp0 libruby1.9.1 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libtasn1-3 libwind0-heimdal libyaml-0-2 openssl rsync ruby1.9.1
Suggested packages:
  git-daemon-run git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-arch git-cvs git-svn git-email git-gui gitk gitweb rng-tools gnutls-bin libsasl2-modules-otp
  libsasl2-modules-ldap libsasl2-modules-sql libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal openssh-server ruby1.9.1-examples ri1.9.1
  graphviz ruby1.9.1-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates foreman git git-core git-man heroku heroku-toolbelt libasn1-8-heimdal libcurl3-gnutls liberror-perl libgcrypt11 libgnutls26
  libgpg-error0 libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libkrb5-26-heimdal libldap-2.4-2
  libp11-kit0 libroken18-heimdal librtmp0 libruby1.9.1 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libtasn1-3 libwind0-heimdal libyaml-0-2 openssl rsync ruby1.9.1
0 upgraded, 32 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 28.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  foreman heroku heroku-toolbelt
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
(precise)root@localhost:/# heroku
bash: heroku: command not found
```

What happened?

Answer (score 1):

In your `apt-get` output, the last line states:

> E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes

If you look at the [actual script Heroku uses to install itself on linux](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh), that corresponds to `apt-get install -y heroku-toolbelt` line.

Try running this: `apt-get install -y --force-yes heroku-toolbelt`