# Heroku Tool belt installation- No Directory exist

Tags: heroku-toolbelt

After installing Heroku Toolbelt, in terminal in Ubuntu , After login authentication

I enter

```
red@red-p7-1039:~$ cd ~/myapp
```

I get error

```
-bash: cd: /home/red/myapp: No such file or directory
```

Other solution tried with no success: As seen in this SOF thread [Heroku command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795498/heroku-command-not-found)

-Manually adding the symlink after installing Toolbelt.

```
 sudo ln -s /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku /usr/bin/heroku
```

It tells me File already exist.

Answer (score 0):

this isn't an issue with the toolbelt at all. You're trying to enter a directory `/home/red/myapp` that does not exist.