# Why is the delete button for a Heroku app greyed out?

Tags: django, heroku

I want to delete an Django app and found two solutions: Use the `delete` button in settings, or from the command line.

The `delete` button doesn't work (the "prohibited" icon shows up). I started a console from within the app to use the command `heroku destroy apps --app MyApp`, but the command "isn't found".

This app has never been set up, so I get lots of "failed" notifications. So I want to remove it. How can I delete this app?

Update: For what it's worth: The problem went away on its own after a day. I was able to use the delete button again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax is wrong. You can delete a heroku app using command:

```
heroku apps:destroy --app Myapp --confirm Myapp
```

or

```
heroku apps:destroy --app Myapp
```

Comment: Appreciate your response. However, the response to both was the same: "bash: heroku: command not found"

Comment: that means there is a problem in running heroku commands in your pc. Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795498/heroku-command-not-found

Comment: Didn't solve my problem because I am using the command on heroku.com, in the app, not on my computer. But I recognize I problem set up my app wrong. The commands you suggested are correct, so i am accepting the answer.