# Bash undeclaring a readonly variable (declare -r var)

Tags: zsh

I can [declare a bash variable as read only](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/declareref.html):

```
var=myname
declare -r var
```

and then when I try to change the value :

```
var=anothername
```

I get (in zsh for example)

```
>>read-only variable: var
```

How can I "undeclare" or unset this variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unset readonly variable in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397069/unset-readonly-variable-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this here [unset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397069/unset-readonly-variable-in-bash):

```
$ cat << EOF| sudo gdb
attach $$
call unbind_variable("var")
detach
EOF
```

Comment: a very UGLY solution.. using gdb for that. Does work and answer the question. But I would never use this in production code..

Answer (score 2):

You can't in bash, readonly means you can't change that variable in anyway, including getting rid of it.