# Why using Bash readonly variable to capture output fails to capture return code $?

Tags: bash, variables

Here's example that tries to execute command and checks if it was executed successfully, while capturing it's output for further processing:

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly OUTPUT=$(foo)
readonly RES=$?

if [[ ${RES} != 0 ]]
then
    echo "failed to execute foo"
    exit 1
else
    echo "foo success: '${OUTPUT}'"
fi
```

It reports that it was a success, even there is no such `foo` executable. But, if I remove `readonly` from `OUTPUT` variable, it preserves erroneous exit code and failure is detected.

I try to use readonly as for "defensive programming" technique as recommended somewhere... but looks like it bites itself in this case.

Is there some clean solution to preserve `readonly` while still capturing exit code of command/subshell? It would be disappointing that one has to remember this kind of exceptional use case, or revert to not using `readonly` ever...

Using Bash 4.2.37(1) on Debian Wheezy.

Comment: Exactly the same issue with `export` by the way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `readonly` is its own command and the exit code that it returns is its own exit code, not the exit code of the command substitution.

From `help readonly`:

> Exit Status:
>   Returns success unless an invalid option is given or NAME is invalid.

So, you need to use two separate commands:

```
$ output=$(false)
$ readonly res=$?
$ readonly output
```

This saves the exit code that you want:

```
$ echo $res
1
```

Short of [entering a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397069/unset-readonly-variable-in-bash#21294582), there is no way to unset a readonly variable.  So, don't set a variable readonly unless you want it to stay constant for the remainder of the bash session.

#### Variation

The two `readonly` commands can be combined into one (hat tip: [Chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)):

```
$ output=$(false)
$ readonly output res=$?
$ echo $res
1
```

#### Aside

It is best practices to use lower- or mixed-case names for your variables.  The system uses all upper-case names and you don't want to overwrite a system variable accidentally.

Comment: To add to your aside on best practice, the `{ }` around `${RES}` are not performing any function.  The `[[  ]]` are performing a textual comparison, to perform an arithmetic comparison use `if (( RES != 0 ))`.

Comment: You can also set the read-only flag on both variables with the same command: `readonly res=$? output`

Comment: @chepner Very good.  Answer updated to show a solution with a single readonly command.