# How to list bash variable attributes

Tags: bash

I'm wondering if there's some command that takes in a variable as an argument, and echoes all of its attributes (integer, array, readonly, etc)

Comment: Your "side question" should be asked separately. Putting more than one distinct topic in a question makes it hard to judge which answer is most correct, and introduces corner cases that make site rules (around voting, duplicate management, &c) hard to handle; that's part of why "Too Broad" is a close reason.

Comment: (also, filesystem utilities -- particularly including those such as `lsattr` and `stat`, or extended versions of `find` capable of metadata lookup -- aren't part of bash, but are provided by your operating system, so they'd need to be asked with a different set of tags).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
$ declare -p var
```

is what you are looking for:

From `help declare`:

> ```
> declare: declare [-aAfFgilnrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
> ...
> -p  display the attributes and value of each NAME
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use `${variable@a}`.  For example:

```
$ declare -ai X=(1 2 3)
$ echo ${X@a}
ai
```

Thanks to user "F. Hauri - Give Up GitHub"; I found that notation in their answer to this unrelated question:  [Unset readonly variable in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397069/unset-readonly-variable-in-bash)

Here is how to get the flags for variable if you have its name in another variable.

```
$ S="X"
$ echo ${!S@a}
ai
```