# LD_PRELOAD in every log in to server

Tags: c, linux, bash, ld, ld-preload

I need to logging all terminal commands in Linux.
I have found correctly working library in C, but it works only when I run `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/bin/bashpreload.so /bin/bash`:

```
# ldd /bin/bash
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffef59f8000)
    /usr/local/bin/bashpreload.so (0x00007fe691323000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007fe691102000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe690efe000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe690b6a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe691524000)
```

If I log in again in the system after this, I will not see the lib with ldd:

```
[root@XXX ~]# LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/bin/bashpreload.so /bin/bash
[root@XXX ~]# ldd /bin/bash
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe481f6000)
    /usr/local/bin/bashpreload.so (0x00007f3f1b808000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f3f1b5e7000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3f1b3e3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3f1b04f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3f1ba09000)
[root@XXX ~]# exit
[root@XXX ~]# logout
Connection to XXX closed.
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC ~]$ ssh root@XXX
root@XXX's password: 
Last login: Tue Dec 19 11:28:22 2017 from YYY
[root@XXX ~]# ldd /bin/bash
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffca2f98000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f19a13ff000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f19a11fb000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f19a0e67000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f19a1620000)
```

And one more trouble: if I use this library, my current PID is changing:

```
Last login: Tue Dec 19 11:28:54 2017 from YYY
[root@XXX ~]# echo "Library is not uploaded"
Library is not uploaded
[root@XXX ~]# echo $$
4639
[root@XXX ~]# LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/bin/bashpreload.so /bin/bash
[root@XXX ~]# echo $$
4654
[root@212-24-57-104 ~]# ps awwufx | grep -B5 [4]654
root      1706  0.0  0.0  66256  1192 ?        Ss   10:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root      4517  0.0  0.0 104636  4644 ?        Ss   11:27   0:00  \_ sshd: root@pts/1 
root      4519  0.0  0.0 108320  1872 pts/1    Ss+  11:27   0:00  |   \_ -bash
root      4637  0.0  0.0 104636  4624 ?        Ss   11:30   0:00  \_ sshd: root@pts/0 
root      4639  0.0  0.0 108320  1872 pts/0    Ss   11:30   0:00  |   \_ -bash
root      4654  0.0  0.0 110376  1956 pts/0    S    11:31   0:00  |       \_ /bin/bash
```

So, I need two things:

1. Find the way to do `LD_PRELOAD` quietly for each logging in user;
2. Know why after this I'm working in the child `/bin/bash` process.

Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone will needs the same as me:
You can add environment variable before user log in via SSH in `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`, syntax like:

```
LD_PRELOAD     DEFAULT=        OVERRIDE="/usr/local/bin/bashpreload.so"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You need to log user actions, have decided on a solution, and are asking questions about that solution.

Even though the solution won't work.

Because using an `LD_PRELOAD` library is not a reliable way to log user commands.

1. The user can just unset the LD_PRELOAD environment variable.  And no, [marking it `readonly` doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397069/unset-readonly-variable-in-bash).  Because it's just a variable in the memory of a process the user controls.
2. You're setting `LD_PRELOAD` to a 64-bit shared object.  Every 32-bit program will now fail to run.
3. However your preloaded library logs data, it does so with the user's permissions/access rights.  Thus the user can spoof the data recorded.

If you need to log user's actions, use a system designed to do that securely:  [auditing](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/chap-system_auditing).

Comment: Auditing not the best solution for my case, I'm exploring alternatives today. Thanks for your advice, the reason 32-bit programs will fail is critical for me.

Comment: "You're setting LD_PRELOAD to a 64-bit shared object. Every 32-bit program will now fail to run" is not true. If the ELF class is different, it'll be simply ignored; nothing untoward will happen except for a diagnostic message and 32-bit programs will still run fine.

Comment: @usr *If the ELF class is different, it'll be simply ignored* **WRONG**.  Try `file /usr/bin/bash`.  You'll see `/usr/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB...`.  Then `export LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libc.so`, a **32-bit** shared object.  After that, enter `/usr/bin/bash` to try running another copy of `bash`.  You get `ld.so.1: bash: fatal: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32` as the 32-bit shared object specified to be loaded by `LD_PRELOAD` is wrong.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Using a 32-bit library as you said produces "ERROR: ld.so: object '/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.". Like I said it's ignored (/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 is the 32-bit libc on my system).

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Find the way to do LD_PRELOAD quietly for each logging in user

You need to set somewhere common for all users such as `/etc/profile` or `/etc/environment`.
See [How to set environment variable for everyone under my linux system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1641477/4389800) for more options/details.

> 2. Know why after this I'm working in the child /bin/bash process.

That's straight-forward - whenever you create a process, its PID is different from its parent :) When you run `/bin/bash`, you obviously creates another shell and that's why `$$` is different. This has nothing to do with `LD_PRELOAD`. If you run `/bin/bash` without `LD_PRELOAD`, you'll observe exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, I still don't understand clearly how LD_PRELOAD works, have to read more. Solution with /etc/profile sounds good, but can you explain me, how can execute library adding in shell-script? adding `LD_PRELOAD /usr/local/bin/mylib.so /bin/bash` will be enough? UPD. It doesn't work :( I can't use `export`, because I need this lib only for /bin/bash

Comment: `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/bin/bashpreload.so` is how you'd set in /etc/profile. But be very careful - depending on what the LD_PRELOAD library does, this may affect users seriously and is possibly a security vulnerability. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117467/192153 for shell specific options. If you want it only for bash you can look at `bashrc` file.