# Change a readonly environment variable in Bash

Tags: bash

If I accidentally set a readonly variable like this:

`declare -r VAR="foo"`

When I should have set it to `bar`.
How can I set it to `bar`?

Thanks

Comment: Exit the shell and start over.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17397069

Comment: Have you tried to just close your shell and open a new one? ;)

Comment: `unset VAR` doesn't work. Thanks, I'll exit and start over as a last resort...

Answer (score 1):

`declare`, as any other statement that modifies a variable within a shell, only does so within the current environment. As the shell does not somehow save its environment on eixst and load it again when restarted, you can just close your shell and open a new one and you'lll have your initial environment back.

It's actually way harder to make changers persist in a shell than to reset them...