# Python activate virtual environment without changing prompt

Tags: python, bash

My shell prompt is read-only, so when trying to activate a venv, I get

```
source myenv/bin/activate
-bash: PS1: readonly variable
```

Looking at the docs here

```
https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/#envvar-VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT
```

> Any virtualenv created when this is set to a non-empty value will not
>   have it’s activate script modify the shell promp

So, I deleted the venv, ran

```
export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1
```

and recreated the virtual environment,

```
virtualenv myenv
```

but it still shows

```
-bash: PS1: readonly variable
```

When I try to source it.

The variable seems to be set correctly

```
env | grep VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What command did you use to create env?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unset readonly variable in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397069/unset-readonly-variable-in-bash)

Comment: @FUNNYDMAN virtualenv spxenv

Comment: @heemayl I am on a shared user account, so I cant use any hacky ways to change the status of the prompt. This is why I am trying make the venv not modify the prompy

Comment: Can you run `set -x` and then the `activate` command, and see where exactly it tries to modify your PS1 still? (`set +x` to return to normal.)

Comment: It appears the export PS1 in the deactivate() function gave the trouble. Although I dont see why this would be called

Comment: In my copy it calls `deactivate nondestructive` as part of the main flow when you `activate`, probably to undo any previously active virtualenv before switching to the one you want. It goes with a comment with a hilarious misspelling of "irrelevant" (line 37 in my copy).

Answer (score 0):

Update `./bin/activate` script to skip updating `PS1` variable:

```
if [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT-}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="$PS1"
    if [ "x" != x ] ; then
        #PS1="$PS1"
    else
        #PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`) $PS1"
    fi
    #export PS1
fi
```

Comment: But it should not be reaching this code if `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT` is set.

Comment: Commenting the export PS1 in the deactivate function seems to have done the trick